# Customizing TestTask

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i want to customize the `TestTask::_processModel()` function. I already customized ModelTask and ControllerTask by copying them to my `src\Shell` folder, changing namespace to `App\Shell\Task` and adding `use Bake\Shell\Task\BakeTask` at top

I did exactly the same with TestTask, but it gets ignored by bake; and i want to avoid editing the default TestTask. Someone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're hoping to change the TestTask used by other bake tasks you'll need to replace the `$tasks` property in your ModelTask and ControllerTask [as they specify Bake.Test](https://github.com/cakephp/bake/blob/f216a89b5be93ea98d86216b1198f022fd6e18df/src/Shell/Task/ModelTask.php#L46-L49).